# Function that returns 1 when a non whole number, 0 when whole number

Tags: functions

The title in this case should be self explanatory. When $x$ has a fractional part greater than $0, y$ should be equal to $1$, and when $x$ is a whole number, $y$ is equal to $0$.

Anything that gives a direct answer (no infinite sums or approximations, etc.) can be used to formulate this *except* the $\text{ceil}()$ rounding function - $\text{floor}()$ may still be used as well as modular operations.

Thank you!

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: It is to generate a function with the characteristics stated above. It may be helpful to know that ceil(x)-floor(x) is identical, though again, the ceiling function may not be used.

Comment: $$f (x) = \begin{cases} 0 & \text{if } x \in \mathbb{Z}\\ 1 & \text{if } x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus  \mathbb{Z}\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{equation*}
-\lfloor -x \rfloor - \lfloor x \rfloor = \begin{cases}
0, & x \in \mathbb Z\\
1, & x \in \mathbb R \setminus \mathbb Z\end{cases}
\end{equation*}

*Note: Here, $\lfloor \cdot \rfloor$ denotes the floor function.*

Comment: Ah, precisely what I was looking for! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

A result of your answer.

$$f(x)=\text{ceil} (x) -\text{floor} (x)=-\text{floor} (-x) -\text{floor} (x)$$

See

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions

For the proof $\text{ceil} (x)= -\text{floor} (-x)$

Comment: Thank you very much for this.

Comment: @RoccoM You can at least upvote the answer if you're not accepting it [and selfishly, I won't recommend that you accept this instead of my answer now — I was first by a minute, anyhow].

Comment: Ha, it's cool M. Vinay those dots were intended as characters so I can send my message won't let me send it if it doesn't have enough to characters. @M.Vinay

Comment: @AhmedS.Attaalla Ah, I did wonder at the dots, but I would've said that anyway.

Comment: I did in fact upvote both and select the right answer, though as I am a new user it gave me the message trailing on "your upvotes don't publicly show until you gain 15 reputation". Not entirely sure why this is, but know I did upvote them haha